# Ender 3 : problem on Z axis for the first layers ONLY

Tags: creality-ender-3, calibration, z-axis

Got a tricky problem here :
I print plate (76x70x3 mm) however there heights (Z-axis) are not correct every time...

[image: This is the current Z-axis, should be 3 mm]

My extruder has been re-calibrated.
My bed has been re-calibrated.

So Firstly I re-calibrate X, Y, and Z-axis with this cube ([thingiverse](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1278865)) :

[image: left before calibration, right after calibration]

Here is detailed data :
[image: Z Axis]

[image: X Axis]

[image: Y Axis]

Here is a picture before and after calibration
You can see the cube is perfectly equal

However, my problem persists. Whatever the plate I want to print, the height is always incorrect. And not only with these pieces with all other plates I created.
All other axes than Z are correct.

It's important to note that Cura always sees the correct size :

[image: Screenshot from Cura]

I really don't understand why only on the plate my height is not correct but for the larger piece, it's correct.

I really want an explanation,
thank's a lot !!

Comment: Just to be sure: if the cube and the plate are printed using the same tempterature of bed? If the bed remains of the same temperature during whole print?  (If I see correcly Cura image, the print is not submerged, but please also doublecheck the Z position of last layer in G-Code.)